# Function to escape text but allow certain tags

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Im trying to create a function to use in Wordpress customiser that will sanatize the input but allow certain tags such as `<b>`. This is what i have so far :

```
function chase_sanitize_textarea( $text ) {
    return esc_textarea( $text );
}
```

Any way I can modify it to allow the bold / italic tags etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a wordpress function, you need to do some work around it. My approach would be to replace the bold and italic tags with a keyword, send it to `esc_textarea`, then replace the keywords after return. This can easily be done with `strtr`.

```
function chase_sanitize_textarea( $text ) {
    $rep_array = array("<b>" => "[START_BOLD]", "</b>" => "[END_BOLD]", "<i>" => "[START_ITALIC]", "</i>" => "[END_ITALIC]"); //set array for tag/keyword switch
    $esc_textarea_value = esc_textarea( strtr($text,$rep_array) ); //replace each tag with its keyword and send to esc_textarea
    return strtr($esc_textarea_value,array_flip($rep_array)); //flip the tag/keyword array and replace the values
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. So the user would add start bold instead of the normal way of doing it ?

Comment: No. The user would type `<b>` just as always. The array changes it to the keyword and back to the tag after wordpress escapes the text.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help.